# Does Google Analytics 4 use value from `document.title`?

Tags: google-analytics-4

According to [[GA4] Page title - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13844738?hl=en), it only uses `title` tag. However, if it's the only source for GA4 to get page title, then there wouldn't be a problem with [having duplicate entries, one has title containing the site name and one not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77307698/3416774).